# VBA to convert XML files to one CSV

Tags: xml, excel, vba, csv

```
Sub xmltoxl()
Dim f As String
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim s As Integer

f =     Dir("C:\Users\Kanye\Downloads" & "\*.xml")
s = 0

Do While Len(f) > 0
    s = s + 1
    Set wbk = Workbooks.OpenXML("C:\Users\Kanye\Downloads" & "\" & f)
wbk.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Kanye\Downloads\Test" & s & ".csv"
wbk.Close False
f = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

I have 900 XML files.  This code takes one XML file and converts it to one CSV.  Is there a way to convert it to one total CSV?

I try the process below but the data is corrupted when opening it (I get this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULO6C.jpg)

```
cd /Users/kanye/Desktop/XML/unzipped
copy *.csv newfile.csv
```

This ends up giving me the data as such https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3lb3.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works.  didn't test it but used code like this plenty of times before.

```css
Sub xmltoxl()
    Dim f As String
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim s As Integer
    Dim tBook As Workbook
    Dim MySht As Worksheet
    
    Set tBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set MySht = tBook.Sheets(1)
    MySht.Cells.ClearContents
    
    f = Dir("C:\Users\Kanye\Downloads" & "\*.xml")
    s = 0
    
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        Set wbk = Workbooks.OpenXML("C:\Users\Kanye\Downloads" & "\" & f)
        If s = 0 Then
           wbk.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy Destination:=MySht.Cells
           LastRow = MySht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
           MySht.Range("Z1:Z" & LastRow) = f
        Else
           LastRow = MySht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
           NextRow = LastRow + 1
           
           wbkLastRow = wbk.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
           
           wbk.Sheets(1).Rows("1:" & wbkLastRow).Copy Destination:=MySht.Rows(NextRow)
           
           NewLastRow = MySht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
           MySht.Range("Z" & NextRow & ":Z" & NewLastRow) = f
        End If
        MySht.Columns("Z").Cut
        MySht.Columns("A").Insert
        
        s = s + 1
        wbk.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Kanye\Downloads\Test" & s & ".csv"
        wbk.Close False
        f = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub

​
```

Comment: After running I get this error https://imgur.com/pc7KRFQ .. After debugging this line is highlighted:             LastRow = LastRow + 1

Comment: Dumb mistake.  I added .Row to the end of Two lines.

Comment: The results are going into sheet one of the workbook with the macro.  I didn't save this workbook.  The code is also creating individual workbooks for each file.

Comment: this looks great, is there a way to include the XML filename in a column for each row that's produced?

Comment: column A would be perfecto

Comment: The code only works if there is data in column A in last row of XML file.  I initially put the filename into column Z then moved column Z to column A at end of code. It is easier to do this way.

Comment: you're a magician. The cut n paste pushes the rows above it 1 to the right every import so I just commented that out and kept it in Z.  Thanks for the help

Comment: if There is data in column Z you can change Z to an empty column.  I usually use last column in spreadsheet something like IA.