# Convert all XML files in a directory to XLS via VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba, xml-parsing, converters

I have around 950 `.xml` files in a directory. I can open the `.xml` files with Excel without any issues. But I'd like to convert all files individually to `.xls` (or `.csv`). I searched the forum and found a few answers (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203403/convert-xml-to-xls) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34124475/vba-to-convert-xml-files-to-one-csv?rq=1)) but could not make it work so far.

The closest I got to what I need is the following code:

```vb
Sub xmltoxl()
    Dim f As String
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim s As Integer
    Dim tBook As Workbook
    Dim MySht As Worksheet

    Set tBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set MySht = tBook.Sheets(1)
    MySht.Cells.ClearContents

    f = Dir("C:\Users\Kanye\Downloads" & "\*.xml")
    s = 0

    Do While Len(f) > 0
        Set wbk = Workbooks.OpenXML("C:\Users\Kanye\Downloads" & "\" & f)
        If s = 0 Then
           wbk.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy Destination:=MySht.Cells
           LastRow = MySht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
           MySht.Range("Z1:Z" & LastRow) = f
        Else
           LastRow = MySht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
           NextRow = LastRow + 1

           wbkLastRow = wbk.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

           wbk.Sheets(1).Rows("1:" & wbkLastRow).Copy Destination:=MySht.Rows(NextRow)

           NewLastRow = MySht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
           MySht.Range("Z" & NextRow & ":Z" & NewLastRow) = f
        End If
        MySht.Columns("Z").Cut
        MySht.Columns("A").Insert

        s = s + 1
        wbk.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Kanye\Downloads\Test" & s & ".csv"
        wbk.Close False
        f = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

However, when I run it, I get back an error after the first `.xml` is opened in the directory. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub XMLTOCSV()
Dim f           As String
Dim p           As String
Dim s           As Integer

p = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads" & "\"
f = Dir(p & "*.xml")
s = 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        s = s + 1
        ConvertXMLtoCSV p & f, p & "Test" & s & ".csv"
        f = Dir()
    Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub ConvertXMLtoCSV(xmlFile, csvFile)
Dim xlApp       As Application
Dim xlBook      As Workbook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.OpenXML(xmlFile, 2)
xlBook.SaveAs csvFile, 6
xlBook.Close False
xlApp.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: This works truly great! Thank you! Is there a way to name the `.csv`files exactly as the original `.xml`? Sorry for asking such noob questions. I never worked with VBA.

Comment: You're welcome. Use this line instead `ConvertXMLtoCSV p & f, p & Replace(f, ".xml", "") & ".csv"`  ... And in this case you don't need the variable s

Answer (score 2):

I've found the most effective method of [Workbook.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas) is to ignore any extension and let the [FileFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat) argument choose that for you.

```
...
wbk.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Kanye\Downloads\Test" & s, fileformat:=xlcsv
wbk.Close savechanges:=False
...
```